# sprite kit enter/exit region

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I need to know when the player enters or exits a (polygon) region. This region is constructed from SKShapeNodes. Each SKShapeNode is a single straight line.

A good approach seemed to do collision detection between the player and these lines via SKPhysicsBody.  I keep track via a flag if the player is inside or outside the region.

```
SKPhysicsBody *pilotPhysics = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(0.1, 0.1)];
    [pilotPhysics setCategoryBitMask:   pilotCategory];
    [pilotPhysics setCollisionBitMask:  pilotCategory];
    [pilotPhysics setContactTestBitMask:    airspaceCategory];
```

But even with a size of 0.1 x 0.1, my SKPhysicsContactDelegate gets multiple beginContact messages. Sometimes the flagged has been flipped so many times within a short interval, it has the wrong value after passing through the perimeter.

What is the correct way to determine when a SKNode enters or exits another SKNode?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the contact delegate is being called multiple times, but I'd guess it had something to do with the physicsBody size being set to be so tiny.

I'd try making the regions' physicsBodies fill the entire region rather than just being a line at the edge, and then use didBeginContact to set the flag to YES and didEndContact to set the flag to NO, rather than just flipping the BOOL every time the delegate is called.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put a CGRect in the same spot as your node that needs to detect if there is another node inside of it? And then use the contains function from the CGRect in the update function to determine whether there is a node inside of it.